# How do you capture the video being streamed into Thunderbolt (3) port using C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I am entirely new to capturing video in C#.

We have a firewire cable that is connected to an old camera live streaming. We have now connected this firewire cable to a thunderbolt 3 port using Apple's FireWire to ThunderBolt 2 and ThunderBolt 2 to 3 to our laptop.

1) What is the best approach to receive and draw the images/video data from a thunderbolt 3 port in .NET Standard/.NET Framework? (I am open to solutions in either of these platforms)

2) Does the .NET framework or standard have such capabilities or do I have to resort to third-party libraries?

2.1) Do you know any open source packages or libraries that can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd do it like with any other video source. First you need to get the device drivers installed so that your old camera gets recognized by Windows as a video source. Then use the multimedia APIs, preferably with a sane .net wrapper.

Some notable examples:

1. EMGU: http://www.emgu.com/ - available directly as a NuGet package.
2. Aforge.net: http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/